# Класс или структура в роли ключа словаря в C#

Tags: c#, классы, struct

Есть словарь Dictionary. В качестве ключа необходимо использовать два строковых значения (некая версия и тип). Получается ключ - экземпляр с двумя полями типа String. Если для ключа использовать класс, то необходимо переопределять метод Equals (ну и хеш до кучи). Если же использовать структуру, то навскидку всё работает без дополнительных методов.

Так вот... действительно ли в случае со структурой, если она состоит из двух полей типа String, не будет проблем? Или же есть подводные камни, ведь String, на сколько я понимаю, не структура.

Comment: Не будет. У string уже реализован equals(), как надо

Comment: `В качестве ключа необходимо использовать два строковых значения` - `Tuple<string,string>`?